# How to disable buffer movement in a particular window in emacs?

Tags: buffers, window

I am trying to figure out if we can disable a particular window from switching the buffer it contains. If anyone has achieved that please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's called a **dedicated window**.

See the Elisp manual, node [Dedicated Windows](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html).

`C-h f set-window-dedicated-p` tells you:

> **`set-window-dedicated-p`** is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>
> `(set-window-dedicated-p WINDOW FLAG)`
>
> Mark `WINDOW` as dedicated according to `FLAG`.
>
> `WINDOW` must be a live window and defaults to the selected one.  `FLAG`
>   non-`nil` means mark `WINDOW` as dedicated to its buffer.  FLAG nil means
>   mark `WINDOW` as non-dedicated.  Return `FLAG`.
>
> When a window is dedicated to its buffer, `display-buffer` will refrain
>   from displaying another buffer in it.  `get-lru-window` and
>   `get-largest-window` treat dedicated windows specially.
>   `delete-windows-on`, `replace-buffer-in-windows`, `quit-window`,
>   `quit-restore-window` and `kill-buffer` can delete a dedicated window
>   and the containing frame.
>
> As a special case, if `FLAG` is `t`, mark `WINDOW` as "strongly" dedicated to
>   its buffer.  Functions like `set-window-buffer` may change the buffer
>   displayed by a window, unless that window is strongly dedicated to its
>   buffer.  If and when `set-window-buffer` displays another buffer in a
>   window, it also makes sure that the window is no more dedicated.